# Finding range value given normal distribution probability, mean, and variance

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am attempting to find an unknown value given the probability of the range of X.  I am unsure of how to calculate the value given the added constants defined in the problem and which values I need to use to look up the z-scores to plug into the x = z + $\mu (\sigma)$. I have found z given probability of 0.95 to be 1.644853.  Not really sure if that is the correct value to use or how to go from here?  Here is the problem:

A random variable X has the distribution $N(1500, (200)^2)$.  Find B, where $P(1500 - B < X < 1500 + B) = 0.95$

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize the distribution and convert N(1500, 200^2) to N(0, 1):

P(1500-B < X < 1500+B) = 0.95

P(-B/200 < (X - 1500)/200 < B/200) = 0.95

Then you should be able to look up the value for B/200 in the table to find where

P(-B/200 < Z < B/200) = 0.95 where Z = $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$= N(0, 1).

Then you can solve for B by setting that value you found in the table equal to B/200.

Comment: [MathJax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).